# Cross-compile FSWEBCAM for Raspberry Pi 2 (YOCTO)

Tags: graphics, cross-compiling, webcam, raspberry-pi2, yocto

I'm using Yocto as OS for my Raspberry Pi.

I want to crosscompile [fswebcam](https://github.com/fsphil/fswebcam) but is showing and error.

---

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/fsphil/fswebcam.git
cd fswebcam
. /opt/poky/2.3/environment-setup-cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi 
mkdir -R build/usr
cd build
../configure --prefix=/home/pablo/test_toolchain/fswebcam/build/usr --host=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc
```

---

Error-> configure: error: GD graphics library not found

Note: I cannot install apt or any package manager, it must be crosscompiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yocto is not an OS... but if you use Yocto as a build system and write an actual recipe for fswebcam this shouldn't be too difficult: According to layers.openembedded.org libgd (the dependency you need) is in meta-oe: https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/1037/.

There is a fswebcam recipe in meta-atmel already, it might work as is or at least work as a starting point: https://github.com/linux4sam/meta-atmel/blob/master/recipes-multimedia/fswebcam/fswebcam_git.bb